# Is it "Yours faithfully" or "Yours sincerely"?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, writing-style, letter-writing, valediction

When should one sign a letter with "Yours faithfully" or "Yours sincerely"?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

This is called "**complimentary close**".

As reported by Oxford Handbook of Commercial Correspondence:

- If the letter begins with Dear Sir, Dear Sirs, Dear Madam, or Dear Sir/Madam, the COMPLIMENTARY CLOSE should be "**Yours faithfully**".
- If the letter begins with a personal name, e.g. Dear Mr James, Dear Mrs Robinson, or Dear Ms Jasmin, it should be "**Yours sincerely**".
- A letter to someone you know well may close with the more informal "Best wishes".

> Note that the Americans tend to close even formal letters with Yours truly or Truly yours, which is unusual in the UK in commercial correspondence.
>
> Avoid closing **old-fashioned phrases**, e.g. We remain yours faithfully, Respectfully yours.

Comment: <rhetorical>I suppose, then, that *Yr. obt. svt.* is right out of the question?</rhetorical>

Comment: I use the following mnemonic. Since the word 'Faith' can be a name, simply ensure that your salutation and closing contain one name. I acknowledge that this ignores more informal letters, but it helps me remember when to use sincerely and when to use faithfully

Comment: I've always remembered this as **Don't put the S's together** - so Sir and Sincerely should not appear together.

Comment: Are these closings still standard in business correspondence in the UK, or do they count as old-fashioned now? (Don't want to open a new question just for this small detail.)

Answer (score 20):

I've been taught the following distinction:

- Use "Yours sincerely" when you know the person you are addressing, i.e. Mr. Smith.
- Use "Yours faithfully" when you are starting your letter with Dear Sir/Madam, or a similar construction.

That being said, it has been my experience that these are used less and less, especially in electronic communications. I would still prefer them in dead-tree letters, but only in the most formal of circumstances (probably when invited to a cup of tea by the Queen of England...).

Comment: Yes, in a printed letter that's a common convention in the UK. However, as you say, other formulae such as just "Sincerely", "Best wishes" or even just "Best" are common especially in more informal business correspondence or e-mail.

Comment: It is as @Manoochehr says if you begin with a personal name not if you know them.

Answer (score 4):

I usually just write "Sincerely,".  I understand it to be a contraction of "I am yours sincerely" or "I am yours faithfully".  If I used it, I'd probably invert it to "Sincerely yours," or "Faithfully yours,". These statements are typically reserved for love letters or other personal correspondence, although faithful could technically describe a business relationship.

Comment: edited my original question, I had wrongly said 'Your faithfully'...

Answer (score 3):

> Best,
>
> The Raven

The modern era does not routinely recognize the "complimentary close" as such, and its use is becoming rather quaint.

Comment: Best what? Best regards? Best wishes? All the best? Best of luck? Best friends for life?

Comment: Sure it's a modern era, but is "Best," what you'd use for a formal letter (like resignation letter etc)?

Comment: No, you shouldn't --- formal correspondence should still use 'yours faithfully' or 'yours sincerely'.

Answer (score 3):

Since Julius didn't specifically ask for a «commercially» correct way of signing a letter, less informal alternatives to what others have posted include:

- Best wishes
- Kind regards
- Yours (truly)
- With love
- All the best
- Best of luck
- Thank You
- Sincerely/Faithfully

Answer (score 2):

I just use "Thank you" - it seems to fit everywhere and doesn't sound like the letter was auto-generated by some letter writing wizard.