# How to end a letter beginning with "To whom it may concern"

Tags: letter-writing

How should one end - ie, sign-off - a letter that begins with "To whom it may concern"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it "Yours faithfully" or "Yours sincerely"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13586/is-it-yours-faithfully-or-yours-sincerely)

Comment: @Matt Эллен: Absolutely. In this case, since the addressee is not named in the opening, the "traditional" closure would be **faithfully**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are referring to the "Complimentary Close" (the word above your signature), it depends on the tone and formality of the letter. If you do not have a specific person to address the letter to, I would use either of these:

Respectfully yours,

or

Sincerely,

Comment: The complimentary close when you don't have the person's name is "yours faithfully".

Comment: Hmm. I would never use that. Can I respectfully ask for a source?

Comment: I give a source in answer below.

Comment: Also [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/13595/3559) cites the Oxford Handbook of Commercial Correspondence.

Comment: @Matt, thank you. Do you think this is a UK/US difference? I don't think I have *ever* seen "yours faithfully" and we do receive letters addressed to "To whom it may concern." It sounds quaint.

Comment: There could be a US/UK divide on this. I don't know enough about US letter writing. This is what I was taught in school, and I'm from the UK.

Comment: I've come across "yours faithfully" before but I kind of agree that it's a bit much. And Matt: the answer you link mentions "Dear Sir/Madam" which sounds more formal than "To whom...etc" and therefore probably suits "Faithfully" better...

Comment: @JLG, Miss Manners is in the US -- I don't know where you are -- but I agree it sounds quaint and old-fashioned.  I don't mind appearing those, however, especially to someone I don't know. ;-)

Comment: Definitely a trans-Atlantic difference. 'Yours sincerely' for the UK if the recipient is named (not 'Sincerely' or 'Sincerely yours'), and 'Yours faithfully' if the recepient is not named.

Answer (score 12):

[According to Miss Manners](http://goo.gl/ZxpE3), the answer is "Yours faithfully".  That is what I use.

Comment: -1 What, are we the recipient's dog now?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake - this is the traditional sign off of a letter for when you don't know the name of the recipient.

Answer (score 3):

"Sincerely" is a fairly common formal sign off.

Answer (score 3):

It partly depends on the contents of the letter.  If I'm submitting, say, a letter of reference, that might warrant something a little different than a general inquiry, a request for a favor, or a formal complaint.

As was stated previously, *Sincerely* is perfectly acceptable, and almost always a safe option.  But if you wanted to soften a complaint, then *Respectfully* might be a better choice.

By default, in the *To-Whom-It-May-Concern* situation, I don't know who will be reading the letter (otherwise, I would have begun with something less generic).  With that in mind, I'll sometimes want to end with my contact information, in case the matter needs further discussion to resolve:

```
If you have any questions, do not hesitate to contact me.

Thank you,                     

John R. Doe
(555) 867-5309
jrdoe18220@ELU.com
```

Answer (score 2):

School taught me to sign letters addressed personally 'yours sincerely' and letters addressed impersonally 'yours faithfully'. Thus, if your salutation is 'To whom it may concern' the corresponding valediction would be 'yours faithfully'.