# Is 'Yours hopefully' formal or informal?

Tags: word-choice, writing-style, letter-writing, valediction

Recently, I had to write an email to one of my professors regarding an urgent matter. I was basically asking him for some guidance in the matter.

I am not a native speaker and normally I end my formal emails with 'Best regards'.  Since this was important to me and I wanted a quick response I wanted to sign with 'Your hopefully'. I didn't know if this would be an appropriate way of ending a letter to a professor.

Is 'Yours hopefully' formal or informal? Is it still used to end letters with?

Note: I have read the following posts.

[Is it "Yours faithfully" or "Yours sincerely"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13586/is-it-yours-faithfully-or-yours-sincerely)
[Is usage of “Yours sincerely” still appropriate?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182282/is-usage-of-yours-sincerely-still-appropriate)

Comment: If the rest of the letter suits it, it sounds fine. It's not a common sign-off, but it fits the theme of sign-offs describing one's attitude / mood / (emotional) posture when composing letters.

Comment: It would probably have made the professor smile, if only for its quaintness of expression. I would though counsel against overuse. Suggesting a date to a good looking other, and ending "yours hopefully" might scupper your chances entirely!

Comment: @WS2 That is why I normally use 'Best regards' to sign-off. As this was a special circumstance and I needed the professor's attention to the urgency of the matter I thought 'Yours hopefully' would be appropriate, which I didn't use by the way.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, "yours sincerely" and "yours faithfully" are the two formal closings with their own rules described in the article you link. I haven't come across "yours hopefully" before and whilst it can make sense, as @Lawrence says, then it could be fine to use. However, if you'd like to stick to more standard endings, I would suggest a closing sentence such as "I hope to hear from you soon" / "I hope for a resolution to this matter", followed by the more standard closings.

Another option which I recall seeing could be "Yours in anticipation".

Finally, depending on your location, there are [US/UK differences to bear in mind](https://www.usingenglish.com/articles/differences-between-british-american-emails.html).