# Faithfully, or sincerely?

Tags: british-english, formality, salutations

When sending letters home our school uses 'Dear Parent' as the salutation.  The person in charge of proof-reading our outgoing correspondence insists that the sign-off should be 'Yours sincerely'.  I was always taught that 'Yours faithfully' should be used when the addressee is not mentioned by name. Does any of this matter, and if so, who is correct?
Thanks English experts, 
Yours faithfully?
Brotherwarren

Comment: You might find [this article](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/yours-faithfully-or-yours-sincerely/) useful.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13586/is-it-yours-faithfully-or-yours-sincerely