# How do we end a Complain letter?

Tags: formality

Do I end a Complain letter of complaint with 'Yours sincerely' or 'Yours truly' or 'Yours faithfully'? Or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it "Yours faithfully" or "Yours sincerely"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13586/is-it-yours-faithfully-or-yours-sincerely)

Comment: It's a letter of complaint, "complaint" is the noun, "complain" is the verb. Do we say a "book of food" or a "book of eat"? ~Do I end a Complain letter of complaint~ is ungrammatical

Comment: ["letter of complaint"](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=870zXLeLEIfgkgWB4biQBw&q=%22letter+of+complaint%22&oq=%22letter+pf+complaint%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0..6557...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.yTWkvKbFZ5E) and see also Oxford Dictionaries https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/writing-help/letters-of-complaint

Answer (score 2):

You'd end the letter with 'Yours sincerely' or 'Sincerely' if you know the person who you're addressing it to, for example, Dear Mr Smith, Dear Ms Hill. 
'Yours faithfully' when you do not know the person who you are writing to - Dear Sir/Madam, Director of... etc. 
'Yours truly' seems a little unusual for closing a letter of complaint. I'd stick with either of the first two.

Comment: Are you British or American? A British person would be unlikely to use "Sincerely" without the "Yours". Nor would they be likely to use "Yours truly". However an American would be unlikely to use "Yours faithfully". You have given what sounds like like a mid-Atlantic answer.